# Why is the explicit constructor not called here?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have 2 questions for this program:

1. Why can't I use the commented structure marked as QUESTION 1. The copy constructor is called instead of the explicit constructor (as far as I can tell, the signature is not ambiguous for the compiler to called the constructor).
2. Do I have to use "delete []p" for the pointer allocated at QUESTION 2 or will the destructor delete it automatically ?

I am new to classes and I'm trying to get the hang of it so thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DIM 2

class Complex {

    double re, im;
    char *name;

public:

    Complex(double re = 1.0, double im = 1.0) {

        Complex::name = new char[9];
        Complex::re = re;
        Complex::im = im;

    }//constructor

    Complex(const Complex &aux) {

        re = aux.re;
        im = aux.im;
        name = aux.name;

    }//copy constructor

    void setReal(double re);
    void setImag(double im);
    void setName(char name[9]);
    double getReal();
    double getImag();
    char *getName();
    Complex sum(Complex);
    Complex dif(Complex);
    Complex multi(Complex);
    Complex div(Complex);

    ~Complex() {

    }//destructor

};

void main() {

    Complex *p = new Complex[DIM];  //QUESTION 2        
                                    //Is the destructor called or do I have do use delete []p ?
    char *name[DIM];

    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {

    //data input    

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)       //freeing memory

        delete name[i];

    //Complex sum(), dif(), prod(), div();              //QUESTION 1
                                                        //why is this calling the copy constructor instead of the explicit 
                                                        //constructor with the deault parameters ?  
    Complex sum(*p), dif(*p), prod(*p), div(*p);    //initialising with the first element using copy constructor    

    for (int i = 1; i < DIM; i++) {

        sum=sum.sum(*(p+i));        
        dif = dif.dif(*(p + i));
        prod = prod.multi(*(p + i));
        div = div.div(*(p + i));

    }

//some data output

    //delete[]p;

}//end main
```

Comment: Can you narrow the code down a bit?

Comment: Ok, just one second.

Comment: Anytime you use `new`, there needs to be a corresponding `delete`; otherwise you leak memory.

Comment: Also: don't use `void main()`; it is not legal C++. Use `int main()` instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I used void main() because I am doing this at university and we are using Visual Studio.(I did notice that is illegal when I tried to write some c++ in Xcode).

Comment: "thank you for taking the time to look into my code" - No thanks, tl;dr. Please read how to make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, if the constructor is allocating memory for the name, should I delete it in the destructor syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line here:

```
Complex sum(), dif(), prod(), div();
```

is not creating `Complex` variables `sum`, `dif`, `prod`, and `div`. It's actually declaring 4 functions that take no arguments and return a `Complex`. Declare it as so:

```
Complex sum, dif, prod, div;
```

Which works as intended

Answer (score 1):

For your second question you have to either set a loop to delete the `name` member variable of each object or write the deconstructor for your class and use `delete []p`.

Comment: As in: `~Complex { delete []p };`

Comment: No the deconstructor should be just `delete name;` and in the main code when you want to delete the array of your objects just type `delete []p;`.

Comment: @mask no, it should be `delete[] name` because it was allocated with `new[]`